DDS Serialization ERROR: Insufficient space
I'm implementing a recoding tool using the 5.3.0 RTI framework, but I'm getting the following error when a large data sample is received:
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_process_primitive_cdr_value:serialization error: insufficient space
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_parametrized_cdr_to_cdr:error copying CDR value
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_parametrized_cdr_to_cdr:error converting from extended CDR to CDR
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_parametrized_cdr_to_cdr:error converting from extended CDR to CDR
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_parametrized_cdr_to_cdr:error converting from extended CDR to CDR
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_parametrized_cdr_to_cdr:error converting from extended CDR to CDR
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_parametrized_cdr_to_cdr:error converting from extended CDR to CDR
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_parametrized_cdr_to_cdr:error converting from extended CDR to CDR
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_parametrized_cdr_to_cdr:error converting from extended CDR to CDR
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_parametrized_cdr_to_cdr:error converting from extended CDR to CDR
DDS_DynamicDataTypePlugin_deserialize:error converting from extended CDR to CDR
PRESCstReaderCollator_storeSampleData:!deserialize

The data sample I’m trying to record is composed of 23 rows, and each row’s size is approximately 1.5 MB. Since the data is large, compression is being used, and the transport used is UDP.
I’ve managed to record a message when the sample is smaller.
So, the issue must be related to buffers. I’ve tried to increase the values of some policies (like rcv_buffer_size, max_fragments_per_sample, max_fragmented_samples), but none of these solved my problem.
What policy could help me solve this issue?
